# Airflow example DAGs take a long time in GUI and the scheduler is showing this: DagFileProcessorManager (PID=...) last sent a heartbeat

Tags: postgresql, sqlite, airflow, airflow-scheduler

While running standard Airflow examples with airflow 2.1.2, DAGs are taking a long time to complete. On every DAG run, this problem occurs. The problem happens when running from the airflow GUI. It isn't a problem when running as a test from the airflow command line. Looking at scheduler log as it runs, this is what is apparent: after a task runs, apparently the DagFileProcessorManager has to be restarted for it to continue to the next tasks, which take 1 to 2 minutes. The restart happens after the absence of heartbeat responses, and this error shows:

{dag_processing.py:414} ERROR - DagFileProcessorManager (PID=67503) last sent a heartbeat 64.25 seconds ago! Restarting it

Question: How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

This fixed the problem:
(1) Use postgresql instead of sqlite.
(2) Switch from SequentialExecutor to LocalExecutor.

Comment: Yep. We also added a warning visible in UI if you use Sequential executor - this warning  will be released in next Airflow version: https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/17133

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to that - we had other similar reports and we decided to make a very clear warning in such case in the UI (will be released in the next version):

https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/17133

[image: Warning when you use sequential executor]